# How to open a Template WorkBook and load its WorkSheets?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Hi i have written code using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll but it is not supported online when i published my website. I then found the EPPlus dll witch is supported online but i am having troubles converting the code to use this new dll.

Old Code useing Interop.Excel:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet[] xlWorkSheet = new Excel.Worksheet[8];

public void ToSpreadSheet()
{ 
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(tempFolderPathAlt + "dvforms\\InvestecTemplate.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

xlWorkSheet[0] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet[1] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2); 
xlWorkSheet[2] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3); 
xlWorkSheet[3] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(4); 
xlWorkSheet[4] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(5); 
xlWorkSheet[5] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(6); 
xlWorkSheet[6] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(7); 
xlWorkSheet[7] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(8); 
}
```

This worked great but now i need to use the EPPlus dll and i'm having problems.

```
 using Excel = OfficeOpenXml;

    Excel.ExcelPackage xlApp;
    Excel.ExcelWorkbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.ExcelWorksheet[] xlWorkSeet = new Excel.ExcelWorksheet[8];

    Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(tempFolderPathAlt + "dvforms\\InvestecTemplate.xlsx");
    Excel.ExcelPackage xlApp = new Excel.ExcelPackage(stream);

//This is where the problems begin, xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(1) is all underlined in red.
    xlWorkSeet[0] = (Excel.ExcelWorksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(1);
```

How do i load the work sheets from my Excel template? I am unsure if i have done the above correctly, Please help i need it badly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(filePath);

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
            {
                ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;

                if (workBook != null)
                {
                    if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach(ExcelWorksheet worksheet in workBook.Worksheets)
                        {
                            xlWorkSeet1[i] = worksheet;
                            i = i + 1;
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

The function Add() takes in a string parameter that's the name of your worksheet. Try:

```
xlWorkSeet[0] = (Excel.ExcelWorksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
```

Comment: I am trying to load a page not create one.

Comment: Then you use this: xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];